# How does tmux list-panes -f (filter) work?

Tags: tmux, filter, panel

I read the man page but I could not find how to use `-f` when using `tmux list-panes`. It seems to be a filter, I assume this works like grep in some way?

Does anyone know how -f works?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `-f` option existed already on some other commands, like `choose-tree` where a hint as to how it works is given. It takes a format string, and, for each pane, if that evaluates to true (i.e. not 0 nor empty) then that pane is listed.

For example, if you have 2 panes, one of which is in tree-mode:

```
$ tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_id} >#{pane_mode}<' 
%0 ><
%1 >tree-mode<
```

then you can show only the one in tree-mode by a matching filter, `#{m:a,b}` matches glob a with string b and is true if they are the same:

```
$ tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_id} >#{pane_mode}<' -f '#{m:tree-mode,#{pane_mode}}'
%1 >tree-mode<
```

To invert the choice to show only panes not in tree mode, use `#{?e,a,b}` which selects string a if string e is true, else b:

```
$ tmux list-panes -F '#{pane_id} >#{pane_mode}<' -f '#{?#{m:tree-mode,#{pane_mode}},0,1}'
%0 ><
```

Comment: Wow thank you for sharing, this is exactly what I was looking for. Curious, how did you figure out how this worked? Was I missing documentation or did you read the source code?

Comment: I just used the enormous man page, but was helped by having followed some of the huge changes tmux has gone through over the years. When I saw the word *filter*, I understood they were refering to the selection mechanism I had seen used in the past for `choose-tree` or `choose-buffer`, when the syntax was less extensive and a bit easier to grasp.